# LaTeX Emergency Stop when using Minted

Tags: pdftex, minted, compilation-error

When using minted in Texstudio, the compiler throws an error which I cant solve, maybe someone with more LaTeX experience has some hints. I am happy to provide extensive information of needed.

**Environment:**

- MS Windows 11 (Version 10.0.22000.739)
- Tex live 2022 (pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24)
- TeXstudio Editor

**Problem description:**

When using the package minted, the compiler aborts with an emergency stop.
The -shell-escape-parameter has been set inside of the Texstudio command configuration:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Other answers on similar questions recommended to turn on batchmode instead of nonstopmode, that however made no difference.

**Error message:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.6)  10 JUL 2022 18:25
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29>
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box50
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 2490
.

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count185
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 14.22636pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 437.46118pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -11%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 24.9436pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -9.43683pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 636.60028pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -39.24942pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1743.
)
\c@part=\count186
\c@chapter=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5715.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5726.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5726.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 5735.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5745.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5745.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5755.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5755.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5766.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5766.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5776.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5776.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box51
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6962.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count193
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6978.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count194
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7146.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
Package: minted 2021/12/24 v2.6 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count195
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2022/04/12 4.2 verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count196
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box52
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count197
\FV@StepNumber=\count198
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count199
\output=\toks17
\linenoprevgraf=\count266
\linenumbersep=\dimen139
\linenumberwidth=\dimen140
\c@linenumber=\count267
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count268
\c@LN@truepage=\count269
\c@internallinenumber=\count270
\c@internallinenumbers=\count271
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen141
\bframerule=\dimen142
\bframesep=\dimen143
\bframebox=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count272
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count273
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box54
\FV@TmpLength=\skip64
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count274
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count275
\FV@LoopCount=\count276
\FV@NCharsBox=\box55
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen144
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count277
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen145
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count278
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen146
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count279
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen147
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count280
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen148
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count281
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count282
\FV@LineBox=\box56
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box57
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen149
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count283
\calc@Bcount=\count284
\calc@Adimen=\dimen150
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen151
\calc@Askip=\skip65
\calc@Bskip=\skip66
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count285
\calc@Cskip=\skip67
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count286
\decimalpart=\count287
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip68
\fb@frw=\dimen152
\fb@frh=\dimen153
\FrameRule=\dimen154
\FrameSep=\dimen155
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count288
\float@exts=\toks18
\float@box=\box58
\@float@everytoks=\toks19
\@floatcapt=\box59
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read3
\minted@bgbox=\box60
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count289
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count290
\@float@every@listing=\toks20
\c@listing=\count291
)
runsystem(if not exist _minted-main mkdir _minted-main)...executed.


(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > ma
in.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> main.aex)...executed.


! Emergency stop.
<read 3> 
         
l.5 \begin{document}
                    ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7574 strings out of 480171
 161188 string characters out of 5891539
 629053 words of memory out of 5000000
 25482 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469559 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 108i,1n,106p,10599b,271s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**Main file:**

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,BCOR=5mm,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small]{yaml}
stack: exchange
  - tex: stuff
    platform: windows
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I reinstalled the Tex Environment but am still getting the same error. But now I get an additional output, maybe that helps to narrow down the problem.

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

```
Use of uninitialized value $ver in scalar chomp at C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 196. Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 197. Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 197.
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order): fmtutil: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes: fmtutil: c:/users/luke/.texlive2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under c:/users/luke/.texlive2022/texmf-var/web2c fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdflatex with pdftex
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl line 718. fmtutil [WARNING]: inifile pdflatex.ini for pdflatex/pdftex not found.
fmtutil [INFO]: not selected formats: 32 fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 1 (pdftex/pdflatex) fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 33 fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1: perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl --user --byfmt pdflatex
Running the command C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt The command name is C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\mktexfmt
Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

Comment: Yes, pygmentize is installed, added in the path variable and can be accessed via cmd.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, I edited the main.tex file as you suggested and posted put the whole error message as well as the tex code into my original post above.

Comment: thanks. I'm on texlive and your example works for me, so it at least confirms  a pygments setup issue not  an error in the document. I'll let a miktex user try....

Comment: sorry I misread, you are on tl, but windows

Comment: Yes, the code also works for me under linux, but my windows setup is still refusing to compile, just cant explain why.

Comment: on windows 10 I have no problems. But it seems to break when it tries to read in the .aex file. Perhaps something (virus protection etc) is preventing its creation.

Comment: Thanks for the input @UlrikeFischer, I am using the built in Virus Defender and turned it off to try if it helps - sadly it doesn't, it still wont compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

After many reinstallations I finally found what caused the error.
During earlier troubleshooting I must have accidentally removed essentials from the system variable PATH, so it could not find the cmd.exe anymore.

The pdf compiler does not state this in its error message. Also, the cmd.exe is needed for the TeXLive installation, the auto downloader though also wont work, but it does not state this in its error message if one does use GUI-installation.

I became aware of this error, as I installed it using the text mode.
Readding the windows binaries to the system variable PATH fixed the problem.

**TL;DR:**
Add "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem" to system variable PATH if it isn't already set (should be at default settings).